# Please make a better contrast between plain text and visited links

Tags: feature-request, color

I touched on a link on the main site and it became darker. But I found it very similar to plain text. Some eyes really feel them the same.

[image: colors]

In fact, the color of plain text is #0B0D0F and for the visited links it is #3E0E0E.

Being underlined doesn't necessarily mean the word(s) are links. This is obviously a link (in the picture), but it could have been just a single word.

Comment: While the contrast isn't great, you can tell it's a link because it has an underline. That's why that underline is there, in fact, because some people have visual impairments that make it extremely hard to differentiate colors (with monochromatic color blindness probably being the most extreme). The underline (or some other appropriate non-color indicator) should really be added where it's missing, since that would help even the people with poor vision.